Legendre addition theorem in $2$ dimensions
We know the addition theorem for Legendre polynomials in spherical coordinates is
$$P_\ell(\cos\gamma)=\dfrac{4\pi}{2\ell +1}\sum_{m=-\ell}^\ell\mathrm Y_{\ell m}(\theta_1,\phi_1)\,\mathrm Y_{\ell m}^\ast(\theta_2,\phi_2)$$
where
$$\cos\gamma=\cos\theta_1\cos\theta_2+\sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2\cos(\phi_1-\phi_2)$$
But what if we were working in polar coordinates? What would be the equivalent in $2$ dimensions? In this case $\cos\gamma$ would simply be $\cos(\phi_1-\phi_2)$ or $\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)$.

Now posted to Overflow, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/475314/addition-theorem-for-legendre-polynomials-in-2-dimensions
